# ¿ Como hacer que el teclado empuje la vista hacia arriba?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Trato de que mi teclado no cubra el boton al momento de dar click en edittext.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/choose_book"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Select a book"
    android:background="#00BCD4"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view_e"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Book"
    android:background="#FFEB3B"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/choose_book" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_e"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_e"
    tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_choose"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
    android:text="Buscar"
    android:background="#8BC34A"
    android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="200dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_e" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código que estas actualmente tratando de realizar por favor. Modifica tu pregunta, revisa [ask].

Comment: Ya agregue el código del diseño que utilizo

Comment: Estas seguro que es el código, lo que sucede es que ese layout no mostraría el botón de abajo aún sin abrir el teclado virtual @freddyDiaz

Comment: si es el código del diseño

Comment: como hago que teclado empuje al botón y al resto del diseño hacia arriba